# Can I run Ubuntu in live mode permanentely?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I have created a thumb-drive installation disk. I can use that to boot up ubuntu in live mode. Once in live mode I try to install ubuntu on another usb-drive but have some difficulties.

Is there any difference between running live-mode on a thumbdrive and installing ubuntu onto another thumbdrive?

Comment: Yes you can. I did it for quite a number of months. the only thing is that you only have 4GB I believe *correct me if I am wrong*, so run wisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference to a pure live session is persistence of your modifications to the system across reboots no matter where you install Ubuntu, i.e. modifications are erased if you turn off the non-persistent live session (or someone pull the thumbdrive out of USB plug and asks politely if he_she might borrow that for a second). Adding a persistence mode to a live session is possible, though, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence or get started with `multisystem`, so that this difference can be compensated.

Note: not answering about differences to an installation on HDD as requested in the question :)